# Beamer vs article cls math rendering

Tags: beamer, math-mode

With `article` class :

```
\documentclass{aricle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{helvet} 

\begin{document}

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

\end{document}
```

Gives :

[image]

With `beamer` class

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}

\usefonttheme{serif}            % Nécessaire pour Fourier
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{helvet} 

\begin{document}

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

\end{document}
```

Gives :

[image]

How to correct `beamer` disposition to have the same as in article ?

Comment: have you tried `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`? (can't test now)

Comment: It works. Thank you, fill free to write answer.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to delete it, maybe this has value as a dupe (so that people who search differently will find this and be redirected to the original) I was just asking other opinions :)

Comment: I voted for a duplicate so our robots will mark it as a duplicate in no time ;)

Comment: @percusse Should I delete the question or live it die by itself ?

Comment: It is going to be in a prfect condition like this forever.